# Difference between shaHex , sha256Hex , sha384Hex , sha512Hex

Tags: java, cryptography, apache-commons

In the apache commons-codec API what is the difference between generating a shaHex, sha256Hex, sha384Hex, sha512Hex?

These are static methods in the [`DigestUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) class.

Comment: try searching for the same topic on `security.stackexchange` too. You'll surely get some answers there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are simply implementations of different algorithms in the SHA family.  See [this section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) of the Wikipedia page on SHA for a summary of the differences.

And in fact the javadoc for [`DigestUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html) makes it clear which methods implement which functions.